# WPF TextBox.Select is asynchronous in Google Japanese IME from Win8?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, textbox, ime

I am using the code below to insert some text inside a TextBox at background, at the same time when user is typing inside it.
This worked very well until Windows 7, even when Asian language input method is on, both MS Japanese IME and Google Japanese IME.

```
private void InsertText(int pos, string text)
{
    textbox.Select(pos, 0);
    textbox.SelectedText = text;
}
```

However, in Windows 8, when Google Japanese IME is used, TextBox.Select() doesn't take effect immediately after it was called.
SelectedText above is not pointing to where pos is until after it releases UI thread.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

P.S. MS IME works well in Win8, however Japanese input candidate is cancelled when calling above method.